# How do I prevent Google from indexing text that is generated by JavaScript?

Tags: google, javascript, search-engine-indexing, googlebot

Google is executing the JavaScript on my password creator website and indexing the random passwords that get generated by the JavaScript.

[image]

The random text that is generated could look spammy to Google and I'm afraid that it will hurt rankings.   It is text that only Googlebot will see (users see their own generated text) so in a sense it is cloaking.   I use some common words as password suggestions and there is a chance they could come out in the order of a popular search phrase.    Also, every time Googlebot renders the page,  it will get different text on it, so my page will end up looking like it changes  way more frequently than it actually does.

The passwords are also showing up in the search results in the text snippet under the link for normal searches.   They look ugly there, so I'd also like to prevent Google from using the generated text for the search snippets.

How do I prevent Googlebot from indexing the password content on my site?    I'd like to have the rest of the content on the page indexed.

Comment: I don't see why "random text" would be considered _spammy_? However, the "Common Words" column (below) might be - but taken in context I would expect Google to simply ignore it.

Comment: Google can get upset when users search for things that aren't on the page but your site comes up anyway.  I take your point that the random text is unlikely to be searched.

Comment: Do users really see this content? I suspect you're trying to fix something that's not broken.

Comment: This text had been coming up in the snippet in the search results even when searching for something like "password creator", so yes, users were seeing it.

Comment: Aside from other aspects... this is actually great snippet for such service .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*robots.txt* can block JavaScript files from Googlebot. http://www.robotstxt.org/ has more information about how to construct a *robots.txt* file.

You could put your JavaScript that shows the password into an external JavaScript file (called *showlists.js*):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    showLists();
});
```

Call that JavaScript file in the page `head`:

```
<script src="/showlists.js">
```

Then disallow it in *robots.txt*:

```
disallow: /showlists.js
```

Then Googlebot would be able to crawl the page, but would not see passwords rendered on the page.

This method is the Google approved way of blocking page elements from Googlebot that avoids cloaking.  The disadvantage of this method is that it requires an external JavaScript  file which can make the page slower to load.

You could test your *robots.txt* file with online testers such as http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/analyzer/

Answer (score 3):

I created a cloaking function in JavaScript:

```
function isBot(){
    return /bot|crawl|slurp|spider/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
}
```

Then I use that function to either show the passwords onload, or to show a message saying why no passwords were generated:

```
if (isBot()){
    $('#isbot').show();
} else {
    showLists();
}
```

Now when I use the "Fetch and Render" feature of "Fetch as Google" from webmaster tools I get the following.

> **This is how Googlebot saw the page:**
>
> [image]
>
> **This is how a visitor to your website would have seen the page:**
>
> [image]

This solution does involve showing different text to visitors than to Google and it could be considered to be a violation of the Google guidelines because it is technically cloaking.

Comment: To be honest, I do not think Google will beat you up over this. The content is still available, however, the sensitive content that is not shown would not be of any value for search and mostly would not be recognized as terms when indexed anyway. The only partial exception is your common words column which may not make sense when indexed anyhow. I suspect that Google is not looking for explicit 1 to 1 matches especially now that so much content is automated or dynamic. I am rather sure that Google is looking for a majority match and some level of consistency which you have.

Comment: As closetnoc states - I don't think the JS generated content is really an issue? Which is worse, hiding some "random content" (which doesn't actually mean anything to anyone) or deliberately cloaking? Another idea (to avoid the cloaking) could be to generate the content on a button click (which you are doing by the looks anyway).

Comment: One of the features of this site is that the passwords come up automatically without you having to click a button.  It makes the site one button click easier to use than the competition.

Comment: Another work around could be that you generate the passwords as `css:after' and when users click the password it'll copy to notepad for them.

Comment: [Setting css :after from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-using-jquery) looks pretty complex and I'd think Googlebot would still be able to see it.  If you think it would work, I'd like to see an answer about it though.

Comment: Wouldn't a noindex robots meta-tag cause google not to index the page at all or does google still process the javascript anyway?

Comment: I'd like the page indexed and ranked in search engines, just not the random text on the page.

Comment: It was my understanding that Google does not index anything contained within `content:''` however, I'm unable to find reliable evidence for this claim.

Comment: Don't use cloaking to try to get around this -- it's against Google's Webmaster Guidelines & makes maintenance a big hassle.

Comment: This is client side code "cloaking".   Googlebot still gets all the same content that normal user agents get, but the rule not to show a feature of the page based on user agent is implemented in JavaScript code.   Googlebot gets to see exactly what is going on.   Is that still considered against the webmaster guidelines?     I also thought cloaking was a problem when it shows text to Googlebot that users *don't* see.   This is the opposite and hides irrelevant text from Googlebot.

Comment: I don't want to implement the robots.txt solution for performance reasons.   All the JavaScript is inline.   Having a JavaScript file that can be blocked by robots.txt adds hundreds of milliseconds to the user experience.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a way you can take advantage of iframes?

Google is able to just look at the source of an iframe, but it can't crawl an iframe directly into the parent page, as far as I know.

So, the iframe source should be *noindex*.

Comment: That might be worth exploring, especially if I could dynamically create the iframe with JavaScript and add the noindex tag with JavaScript.

Comment: I was thinking: implement iframes for your password generator section div in your original document (or for every single column: random, writable, etc.). Use them to call different webpages with password generator scripts, and these webpages should have noindex in their <head> tag, or just use robots.txt to prevent crawling. Maybe it's simpler and it may work.

Comment: Might the `iframe` have accessibility issues? (Not sure what, just wondering.)

Comment: Yes. In fact there are some actions to take, like implementing a title parameter for the tag, and writing text inside the iframe for people who cannot read the content (it would be like a <noframe> tag).

Comment: What makes including an iframed file faster than including a javascript file? 

From my experience, iframe content does get indexed and can be considered part of the parent. You would still have to block it via robots.txt

Comment: That's true, but at the moment I considered html to be the fastest to implement. And if users have javascript disabled, it still works.