# For webpages using jQuery, will the Googlebot index them on "page load" or after the "page ready" state?

Tags: seo, javascript, search-engine-indexing, googlebot, jquery

Will the Googlebot index a webpage on "page load" or after the "page ready" state. The reason I'm asking is because I'm trying to change my `h1` and `h2` tags using jQuery on page **Load**.

Comment: It might be helpful if you add some more details about your code.

Comment: Check the "Fetch **and Render**" tool in Google Search Console (aka GWT).

Answer (score 3):

Google indexes the text after the page is fully ready.   I have a password creation site that uses JavaScript to write random passwords into the page on jQuery's `$(document).ready`.   Googlebot was indexing those randomly generated passwords.

I've previously asked how to prevent that indexing because random passwords aren't text that should be indexed: [How do I prevent Google from indexing text that is generated by JavaScript?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81442/how-do-i-prevent-google-from-indexing-text-that-is-generated-by-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

An article I'd read earlier this month revealed tests that have seen Googlebot execute Javascript and process the resulting Document Object Model (DOM), rather than simply looking at the HTML source code, you might find this a helpful read:

[SearchEngineLand: Tested Googlebot Crawls Javascript](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157) (May 2015)

Answer (score -4):

It doesn't matter. Google reads your markup and doesn't render the content. If they read your javascript, then they can tell if its manipulating those headings, no matter when it happens.

Comment: "doesn't render the content" - Google provides the "Fetch **and Render**" tool for this very purpose.

Comment: Yes but that's for the developer, not for Google's sake. Search engines need not render content to understand it.

Comment: "not for Google's sake"? The tool is provided to give you a very good idea of what the search engine is going to be able to index. Google is not going to index content that does not at some point appear on the rendered page as users are not going to see it either - bad experience all round.

Comment: @w3d You just repeated what I said. The tool is for your use, not Google's.

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect.  Google is now indexing content that is only rendered by JavaScript and not in the page source.  I've had to ask how to [prevent it from doing so](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81442/how-do-i-prevent-google-from-indexing-text-that-is-generated-by-javascript).

Comment: I was basically refuting your statement that "Google... doesn't render the content". Google **does** render the content. Yes, the "Fetch and Render" tool is for the developer. It is a tool to see _how_ Googlebot _renders_ the content. In other words, "how Googlebot sees your page".

Comment: @StephenOstermiller There's a difference between rendering content and reading javascript. Google will not run javascript animations, nor changes colors or move elements on a page just because it's in the code. It's not necessary for them to do so to understand what the javascript is doing. They don't need to wait for the page to render, as the question is asking about, because rendering the page completely is a waste of effort when all that's needed is the markup.

Comment: The only way they could be indexing the passwords from my password creator site would be rendering the page completely and then scraping the text off of it.  The passwords are written into the page on document ready.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Incorrect. Javascript can be examined and executed without a web page at all.

Comment: @Rob why would Google go through the effort of running Javascript without rendering it too?  How is it that they can judge mobile  support? How do they gauge that an object is or is not masked out of viewport?

Comment: @dhaupin What would they do with the result of the rendering? What does something display outside the viewport have to do with search results? Other than an attempt to hide the element which will be detected just by reading the CSS and javascript. You don't need to generate the DOM, layout all the elements, download the images, generate animation, etc. to tell what code is trying to do. It takes time to render a web page that provides no value in any way, shape or form. You don't draw with pencil and paper a web page every time you read the markup, do you? But you can tell what markup doing.

Comment: @Rob they do many things with the result. So they program all that extra extraction logic in to make it "predict" what will happen when the  code runs but they don't actually run it eh? You do realize that's immensely harder and more inaccurate than just running the scripts right? Now they don't even run the DOM either? Whaaa? Have you actually read how Gbot works and the G specs or are you just pulling all of this out of the magic hat too? And generally what I do to see a script work is run it rather than try to estimate what will happen.

Comment: @dhaupin That's not what I said but I'm bored with this thread so I'll leave you with your assumptions.